# Update the library in package.json

Tags: reactjs, package

I want to update the libraries in package.json in a batch, so I executed the command ② after executing the command ①.
After that, I executed the `yarn` command and the libraries were installed, but when I executed `npm install` after executing the commands (1) and (2), I got an error.
Why does npm install give me an error?

```
①rm -rf node_modules yarn.lock
②　npx npm-check-updates -u
```

error

```
npm ERR!   react@"18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@material-ui/core
npm ERR!   @material-ui/core@"^4.12.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /user/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a dependency conflict in your packages.
@material-ui/core@4.12.4 needs react 16/17 but you are using react 18

upgrade to material-ui v5

OR

use --force flag knowing that there may be some breaking changes

```
npm install --force
```